# VsCode Server, high CPU use

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl2

I noticed that my WSL2 instance uses a lot of CPU and according to `top` this is `node` from the VsCode servers. If I kill all my VsCode instances the CPU usage drastically drops.

To reproduce the issue I can just `mkdir dummy && cd dummy && code .`. Once the WSL connection is established I have a `node` process running on WSL2 that uses about 120% of one single CPU.

How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See if one of the following is your issue: [issue1](https://medium.com/good-robot/use-visual-studio-code-remote-ssh-sftp-without-crashing-your-server-a1dc2ef0936d) and [issue2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898).

Comment: Those links didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably not a problem with VsCode, but an extension. Try to manually disable each extension that is installed in WSL.

In you particular case look at the **Stream Deck** extension that may be trying to establish a connection from the WSL side.